# Why does $\forall g\in G, g^2\in H\cap K$ imply $G/(H\cap K)\cong V$, the Klein $4$-group in this instance?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

**The setup**: For a group $G$, let's say we have two subgroups, $H$ and $K$. Assume that both subgroups have index $2$ in $G$. We want to show that $G/(H\cap K)\cong V$, the Klein $4$-group.

Edit**: We also require that $H\cap K\neq H$.

**The sketch of the proof**: I begin by finding that $[G:H\cap K]=4$. Up to isomorphism, there are two groups of order four, $V$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

I am told that showing $g^2 \in H\cap K, \forall g\in G$ ends the proof, but am not sure why this is the case (if someone could elaborate on this fact, that'd be appreciated).

**Showing $g^2 \in H\cap K, \forall g\in G$**: I have also included this section for future readers and for critique.

There are two cases. Case (1): $g\in H\cap K$. Since $H\cap K$ is a subgroup, $g^2\in H\cap K$ and we are done.

Case (2): $g\notin H\cap K$. Suffices to show that $g^2\in H$ and $g^2\in K$. Since the index of $H$ in $G$ is $2$, $H$ partitions $G$ into two cosets of $H$, one of which is $H$ itself.

Assume for contradiction that $g^2\notin H$. Since $g\notin H$, $g^2\in gH$, the only other coset in $G$. Hence, $g^2=gh$ for $h\in H$. Therefore, $g=h\in H$, a contradiction. Hence, $g^2\in H$. (The proof is symmetric for $K$.)

Therefore, $g^2 \in H\cap K, \forall g\in G$.

Comment: The setup: Take $H=K$. Then the index $[G:H\cap K]=2$, and not $4$. So something is wrong.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot a crucial assumption in the problem. That is, $H \cap K\neq H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that for all $g\in G$, $g^2\in H\cap K$ is the same as showing that for all $g\in G/(H\cap K)$, $g^2=e$. Thus if this is true then every element in your group is it's own inverse, which is not true for $\Bbb Z_4$, take $1$. Thus if you have only two choices then it must be the Klein 4 group. As pointed out in the comments, however, something is wrong since $H=K$ clearly causes this to fail.